# how to remove a string in a 2d array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, string

Given a 2d array of chars, or in other words, an array of strings with a given size, for example:

```
char array[100][6];
```

and the array is filled like this:

```
{"john", "mark", "megan"} and so on...
```

How can i remove a given word? For example, removing "mark".

I read somewhere that we have to replace the string to be removed with the next one.

The code i have so far:

```
void remove_string(char array[100][6], char *string, int array_size){
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
        if(strcmp(array[i], string) == 0){
            for(int j = i; j < array_size; j++){
                strcpy(array[j], array[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result after removing "mark":

```
{"john", "megan"}
```

The code seems to work, but can it be done without using another loop?

I also tought about copying all the words except for the one to be removed to another array and return the new array, but i cant seem to find away to only copying "the other words".

Comment: What do you mean remove? Can;t you overwrite the content with a null string? The size is not gonna change, anyway.

Comment: @SouravGhosh but replacing a word with null string would leave a blank spot in the array if i am trying to remove a string in the middle of 2 others, no?

Comment: yes, and any reason that cannot be accepted? Remember, it's an array, not a linked list.

Comment: @MiguelD then swap the blank spot with the last one (if the order is not important) or move all the elements after it one step up (if order is important).

Comment: @SouravGhosh then something like this would happen {"john", "", "megan"} and i want this: {"john", "megan"}, maybe i should update the question to be more clear

Comment: in that case, take @AjayBrahmakshatriya 's advice.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya that is what i did in the example code, but i am looking for a away to do it without using another loop, if thats possible

Comment: @MiguelD is the ordering of the names important?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya for the time of removing no, cause i will sort them after the deletion is done

Comment: @MiguelD, I am posting an answer to your question. Hold on.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: If the array is sorted anyway, even swapping is not necessary, at least if using the right way of compardion.

Comment: @alk yes, I wrote the answer without swapping. Will delete the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a loop in your function that iterates over the elements. You can use the same loop to delete the elements in place.

What you need is another integer while iterating. This integer will hold the index where the current element needs to be moved in the array.

In your function declare a new integer as -

```
int new_position = 0;
```

Now inside your loop, you normally check if the string matches the deletion string -

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    if (strcmp(array[i], string) == 0) {
        // Do nothing. and continue
        continue;       
    }
    if (new_position != i) {
        //Move the other elements 
        array[new_position] = array[i];
    }
    new_position++;
}

array_size = new_position;
```

This will also automatically preserve the order of the elements and delete all the matching elements.

Comment: what is are you doing nothing when it finds the string to be removed? shouldnt you update the new_position variable there?

Comment: @MiguelD we don't update `new_position` because we want to skip that element. We only copy the elements that do not match.

Comment: what i noticed when using your code is that you are always overwritting the first word of the array, if this is the array {"john", "mark", "megan", "chad"}; and i delete "mark" i get {"megan", "chad"};

Comment: @MiguelD oops! There was a mistake. Fixed it

Comment: @MiguelD, note that since `array_size` is being updated, you should return the new size or pass the `array_size` by reference (using a pointer to `int`) and update it in place.

Comment: @MiguelD just read the last comment once. It is important for your function.

Answer (score 1):

you cant "remove" the string from this kind of table. You can only make it zero size

```
char *remove_string(char *arr, size_t nstrings, size_t strlength, size_t string)
{
    if (!arr || string >= nstrings) retun NULL;
    arr[strlrength * string] = 0;
    return arr + strlrength * string
}
```

and same with the `**` char pointer table (assuming that the space was allocated for the strings). It will not work if you have assigned the pointers with addresses of the ReadOnly string literals.

```
char *remove_string_from_table_of_pointers(char **arr, size_t nstrings, size_t string)
{
    if (!arr || string >= nstrings) retun NULL;
    if(arr[string]) arr[string][0] = 0;
    return arr[string];
}
```

If the strings were "malloced" you can also completely remove the string, freeing the memory

```
int completely_remove_string_from_table_of_pointers(char **arr, size_t nstrings, size_t string)
{
    if (!arr || string >= nstrings) retun -1;
    if(arr[string]) free(arr[string]);
    arr[string] = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so is preferable to use char **array over char array[100][6] in this case? i only sticked with  char array[100][6] because in my case i know from the start the max size of the array and max size a string can be

Comment: No - it depends of your needs. No gold rules.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove items from fixed-size arrays. What you will have to do is to move all items from index *n* and beyond one step forward in the array, overwriting the previous one.

This is quite ineffective, and this is the reason why linked lists were invented: they are far more suitable than arrays when one needs to add/remove items in the middle of a container.

Comment: "This is quite ineffective, and this is the reason why linked lists were invented" but removing an item at a given index in a linked list is ~O(n) and i think with the same time it can be done using arrays too, no?

Comment: @MiguelD "Big O" is mostly a useless metric for real-world computer programs. What's important in determining how slow the array version is, is not so much the number of moves, as the size of one data item. Also, data cache may or may not be a factor. And even if the data item is small, finding one item in a linked list and then swapping some pointers, is going to be much faster than moving an array. Also, a linked list is not necessarily heap allocated, so the little extra overhead for heap allocation is not necessarily there.